# char or float overflow

Tags: c, floating-point, char, overflow

Unsure how to tell if an overflow is possible. I am given this sample code:

```
char x;  
float f, g;  
// some values get assigned to x and f here...  
g = f + x;
```

Can someone please explain?

Comment: You may (or may not) find this useful: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `float`, at its highest limits (binary exponent of 127), does not have sufficient precision (23 bits) to show a difference of the largest possible `char` (127, 7 bits), and so overflow is not possible since addition will have no effect (a precision of 127-7=120 would be required).

Comment: Hmm, lost me there. I think I followed you better when you said that g was not sufficient to save an overflow since it was type `float`? If g were say, type `double`, this would save the overflow right?

Comment: @raphnguyn Basically, a float can contain a number around [1e38](http://steve.hollasch.net/cgindex/coding/ieeefloat.html). A character has has a max value of 127. You cannot 1e38 into 127. Therefore, it "overflows."

Comment: Congrats on hitting perfect 100k! (Yep, one upvote was mine.)

Comment: @raphnguyen: At its highest limits, you would need to add 2**(127-23)=2**104 in order to even notice a single digit change in a `float`, much less overflow it. @BoltClock: Thanks.